# None of the outlets in the kitchen are working

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

The other day I switched on the garbage disposal and now none of the outlets in the kitchen work. This circuit is GFCI protected from the panel but the GFCI breaker in the panel is not tripping. When I test the outlets with the breaker on they show hot on the hot and neutral sides. I have replaced the outlet feeding the garbage disposal but this did not work. I have also replaced the switch controlling the disposal but still nothing works. I tested the wires at the breaker and they appear normal. This condition exists from the first line on the circuit to the last. Does anybody know what could be going on here?

Comment: What are you using to test voltage with? I don't understand how you tested hot on the neutral (white) wire: did you test for voltage between the neutral (white) and the ground wire? Since the problem started when you switched on the disposal, I would think there's something wrong there. Maybe the disposal is shorting out. Try disconnecting the disposal wires and connecting everything else.

Answer (score 5):

If you are showing hot on neutral this is an indication of an open neutral on the circuit with a load attached. You are reading the voltage on the neutral through the load.
Find the open neutral and you'll find your solution. It could be anywhere in the circuit, from the panel through any box or outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the GFCI breaker in the panel is bad. You should 120V from hot to the neutral terminals on the breaker. If you have 120V from the neutral/ground bus to the neutral terminal on the GFCI breaker with the disposal on then there is an open in the neutral side of the breaker or the neutral wire from the breaker to the neutral bus is broken or loose.